# Group theory in non-European/subaltern cultures?

Tags: mathematics, abstract-algebra, mathematics-social-history, group-theory, ancient-india

I'm doing undergraduate research on the history of abstract algebra (specifically permutation groups) and the notion of symmetric groups in indigenous artwork has come up several times. Is anyone aware of evidence of this 'intrinsic' human desire to construct groups I could point to? Or maybe some natural phenomena that conform to the definition of group? I'd like to have specific examples I can explain (and possibly map some ideas of formalized group theory onto). Thanks!

(I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4793503/group-theory-in-non-european-subaltern-cultures) on Math stack exchange too but I'm not sure how to move it over...sorry for the duplicate!)